# Build issue in devops pipeline with nuget restore latest version

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When I try to run the *build pipeline* from `Azure DevOps`, I am getting an error with **NuGet** restore *task* for the latest version. It is not happening every time. After multiple attempts, the pipeline is getting successfully executed.

```
NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException: Exception of type 'NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException' was thrown.
   at NuGet.CommandLine.MsBuildUtility.<GetProjectReferencesAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<GetDependencyGraphSpecAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<DetermineInputsFromMSBuildAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Installing nuget version 4.7.1 using Nuget tool installer is also creating same issue with build pipeline.. first time it got success but on the next run it got failed with same error

Answer (score 0):

> Build issue in devops pipeline with nuget restore latest version

This is a known issue about the nuget from the version `4.8.1`, and this issue has not been solved in the version (5.4).

NuGet experts replied:

> I'd imagine this is a fall out from the perf work with
>   `SkipNonExistentTargets`.
>
> The issue here is that these projects likely have non-existing
>   imports. Projects like take a toll on the msbuild evaluation and make
>   it significantly slower.
>
> Try setting `RestoreUseSkipNonexistentTargets="false"`

To resolve this issue, we could use the [NuGet tool installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops) task to install the old version nuget like: `4.7.1`. Or we could try to set the property  `RestoreUseSkipNonexistentTargets="false"` in a `Directory.Build.Props` at the root of your repo.

Please check the open issue [7796](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7796) on github for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Installing nuget version 4.7.1 using Nuget tool installer is also creating same issue with build pipeline

Comment: @Madhu, How about set set the property RestoreUseSkipNonexistentTargets="false" in a Directory.Build.Props at the root of your repo?

Comment: I have added one file with the name 'Directory.Build.props' in the mail directory of the repo. In that file i have added the code   <Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <RestoreUseSkipNonexistentTargets>false</RestoreUseSkipNonexistentTargets>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>      Is this fine or did i miss anything...

Comment: @Madhu, I do not know if the folder **mail** directory is correct for you, but the file `Directory.Build.props` should be set in the parent directory of your projects or in the solution directory. If you still have this issue? If yes, would you please share a image about your nuget restore task settings in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Building a solution will hide the real error message. Try **building each project separately** so that you can get the error message and fix it.